# ¿Por que mi tabla en mysql no se actualiza usando php?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, update

He estado tratando de actualizar una tabla de mysql que tengo en phpmyadmin sin tener éxito alguno. Los datos que ingreso para actualizar dicha tabla si logran ser enviados mediante el método POST a otra página php pero no se logran actualizar en la tabla. Mientras que se establezco valores predeterminados en las variables la consulta si actualiza los datos en la tabla de mysql.

**PHP en el que eligo el nombre e ingreso la nacionalidad que deseo editar en la tabla:**

```html
<div style="display:">

  <?php

   $mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","root","","bdlicitaciones"); //servidor, usuario de base de datos, contraseña del usuario, nombre de base de datos

   if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
   }

  ?>




  <?php

  /*
   * Código para mostrar datos dinámicamente en un combobox.
   */


  $query = 'SELECT * FROM oferentes';

  $result = $mysqli->query($query);

  ?>
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="input-field col s12 m10 l10">
    <p style="text-align:left;"> ID del Oferente:</p>
    <select  id="IDOferente" class="browser-default col s12 m10 l10" name="IDOferente">

      <?php
      while ( $row = $result->fetch_array() )
      {
          ?>


       <option value=" <?php echo $row['ID_Oferente'] ?> " >
         <?php echo $row['ID_Oferente']; ?>

       </option>

       <?php
   }
   ?>
    </select>
    </div>
  </div>




</div>

HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Actualizar1.php</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div align="center">
<h1>Actualizar un registro</h1>
<br>

<form class="col s12 m12 l12 " action="prueba4.php" method="post" name="forminsertar" id="forminsertar">

  <?php

  $query = 'SELECT NombreOferente FROM oferentes';

  $result = $mysqli->query($query);


   ?>

   <div class="row ">
     <div class="input-field col s12 m10 l10">
     <p style="text-align:left;"> ID del Oferente:</p>
     <select  id="oferentes2" class="browser-default col s12 m10 l10" name="oferentes2" >

       <?php
       while ( $row = $result->fetch_array() )
       {
           ?>


        <option value=" <?php echo $row['NombreOferente'] ?> " >
          <?php echo $row['NombreOferente']; ?>

        </option>

        <?php
    }
    ?>
     </select>

     <br>
Nacionalidad<br>
<INPUT id="nacionalidad" TYPE="TEXT" NAME="nacionalidad"><br>
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Actualizar">

 
</FORM>
</div>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**PHP al cual se envía el formulario y en el que se ejecuta el query que deberia de actualizar la tabla**

```html
<div style="display:">

  <HTML>
  <HEAD>
  <TITLE>Actualizar2.php</TITLE>
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>

<?php

$nacionalidad1 = $_POST['nacionalidad'];
?>
<?php

$nombre = $_POST['oferentes2'];

 ?>

  <?php

   $mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","root","","bdlicitaciones"); //servidor, usuario de base de datos, contraseña del usuario, nombre de base de datos

   if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo 'Conexion Fallida : ', mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
   }







   $sql="UPDATE oferentes SET Nacionalidad='$nacionalidad1' WHERE NombreOferente='$nombre'";
   $rs =mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
   if($rs){

       echo "Records inserted successfully.";

   } else{

       echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($mysqli);

   }

   mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>



<h1><div align="center">Registro Actualizado</div></h1>
<div align="center"><a href="lectura.php">Visualizar el contenido de la base</a></div>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: quitale el echo a la variable $nacionalidad1

Comment: tu select se llama oferentes2 pero estas pidiendo OferenteADJ2

Comment: Lee sobre qué es la inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP. El código compartido es vulnerable a ese tipo de ataques.

Comment: @alanfcm gracias por los comentarios, eso que mencionas es por que estuve realizando varias pruebas y olvidé dejarlo como estaba originalmente. Ya lo corregí pero sigue sin actualizar la tabla

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro es debido a esto que mencionas que el query no actualiza la tabla?

Comment: @Rodriguez1222 no, es algo a tener en cuenta aparte por seguridad. Perdón por no especificarlo mejor.

Comment: Pero... ¿qué hace tu código? ¿Imprime el mensaje `ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($mysqli);`?, en ese caso, ¿qué error imprime, el de `DUPLICATED KEY...` u otro error del tipo `table` o `column not exists...` algo así?, ¿o imprime `Records inserted successfully` pero no actualiza? Deberías indicar cuál es el comportamiento de tu código, en qué bloques entra y que imprime en pantalla.

Comment: ¿Qué valores tienen las variables que usas para actualizar?

Comment: @A.Cedano disculpa si no fui muy claro, en el primer php simplemente se elige el nombre de una persona que se encuentra en una tabla de mysql y se ingresa en un campo una nacionalidad. Este dato que se ingrese sera para modifica uno que ya exista en la tabla segun el nombre que se hayan seleccionado. Estos datos se mandan atraves del metodo post al segundo php. Los datos son recibidos y se almacenan en variables declaradas. Luego se ejecuta el query pero por algun motivo este no actualiza.

Comment: Espero haberme dado a entender un poco mejor. Como menciono arriba si yo a las variables del segundo php le ingreso valores predeterminados como por ejemplo $nacionalidad1 = 'Honduras' y $nombre = 'Allan' (este ultimo ya existe en la base de datos) el query se ejecuta sin problemas y actualiza la tabla.

Comment: Lo que dices en tu último comentario es el comportamiento correcto, pues si el registro no existe en la tabla no se puede actualizar, por tanto, si el `WHERE` no se cumple no habrá `UPDATE`... ¿No estarás confundiendo actualización (`UPDATE`) con inserción de nuevos registros (`INSERT`)? Son dos cosas totalmente distintas.

Comment: @A.Cedano entiendo lo que dices amigo. Pero no, es UPDATE lo que estoy tratando de utilizar. Use el ejemplo de $nombre= 'Allan' por que ese nombre como tal existe en la tabla. Entonces si en el primer php con el dropdown de los nombre yo escojo Allan y en nacionalidad escribo "Honduras" al mandar este formulario al segundo php este no actualiza la tabla. Mientras que si yo por default le otorgo los valores de 'Allan' y 'Honduras' a las variables $nombre y $nacionalidad1 respectivamente el query se ejecuta sin problema y la tabla si se actualiza.

Comment: En ese caso el problema es el `$_POST`  que no está recibiendo bien los datos entonces. ¿Por qué no depuras las variables que intervienen en la consulta con `var_dump($nombre);` y `var_dump($nacionalidad1);` y comentas los resultados de cada una de esas pruebas?

Comment: @A.Cedano disculpa que conteste hasta ahorita, anduve de viaje. Encontré que el problema no es el $_POST. El problema de alguna manera es valor que manda el select "oferentes2", el query en si pareciera no reconocerlo. El valor que se manda del primer php si llega al segundo ya que lo muestra mediante un echo. Probe mandando un valor de un select cualquiera el cual no trae datos de la base y por alguna razón el valor de este select el query si lo acepta ya que si actualiza ya tabla en mysql. Espero darme a entender.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres decir, lo cierto es que si lo tienes como muestras en la pregunta y el archivo PHP es el correcto, no tiene por qué no funcionar. Cuando tu mandas datos por `POST` (un formulario por ejemplo) lo que se hace es crearse un array cuyas claves son cada valor de la etiqueta `name` de los elementos posteados, y el valor es el dato que haya dentro del elemento. En este caso tú tienes un `select` cuyo name es `oferentes2`, por lo tanto, debería recogerlo, a no ser que tengas algún error o que los archivos estén apuntando a otros distintos y no te hayas dado cuenta.

Comment: @A.Cedano trataré de explicarme mejor. El select que tu ves de "oferentes2" es un select que muestra las opciones tomando los datos de una tabla en mysql. Al elegir cualquiera de las opciones disponibles el dato que haya sido seleccionado al parecer el query no lo lee. Para efecto de prueba cree otro select similar pero que no toma los datos de ninguna tabla, sino que yo los asigno manualmente. Sea cual sea la opción que yo elija en este select de prueba por algún motivo el query si logra entenderlo y logra actualizar la tabla.

Comment: @A.Cedano la única diferencia entre ambos selects es que uno carga las opciones desde una tabla en mysql mientras que el otro contiene los mismos valores de la tabla en mysql pero estos se los asigno yo predeterminadamente en el php y es este último el que si funciona con el query. No logro entender por que con el que lee los datos desde mysql el query no funciona.

Comment: Deberías revisar el código fuente (HTML) del `select` que no te funciona, puede que esto: `<option value=" <?php echo $row['NombreOferente'] ?> " >
          <?php echo $row['NombreOferente']; ?>
        </option>` tenga algún error en alguna parte. Con la página cargada, visualiza el código fuente y busca ese `select`, si puedes muestra un trozo de él en un comentario, partiendo de la parte del inicio...

Comment: @A.Cedano    <select  id="oferentes2" class="browser-default col s12 m10 l10" name="oferentes2" >

       <?php
       while ( $row = $result->fetch_array() )
       {
           ?>


        <option value=" <?php echo $row['NombreOferente'] ?> " >
          <?php echo $row['NombreOferente']; ?>

        </option>

        <?php
    }
    ?>
     </select>

Comment: @A.Cedano ese es el select completo amigo, por comentario parece que se ve todo un desastre. El select al menos ya corriendo el php funciona bien, carga los datos de la tabla en mysql y los muestra entre sus opciones. Igual el valor elegido es enviado al segundo php y este se visualiza mediante un echo. Lo cual quiere decir que el valor logra llegar al segundo php pero por algún motivo extraño es el query el cual pareciera no leer este valor.